# Writing and accessing JSON file saved to internal memory

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to save a JSON to internal memory to reduce the number of times my app has to access the web, and to speed up performance. The issue I'm having is it seems that the file is never created.

Write to file:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Get JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            JSONObject runeInfo = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);
            Log.i("Main JSON", "" + json);

            // Get JSON containing Rune Info and cache it
            String jsonString = runeInfo.toString();
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "runesInfo.json");

            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fOut = openFileOutput("runesInfo.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fOut.write(jsonString.getBytes());
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Cache", "Cache Complete");

            return json;
        }
```

Read from file:

```
 public class GetRunes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(String[] runeId) {

            String readJson = null;
            String name = null;

            try {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("runesInfo.json");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

                fis.read(readJson.getBytes());
                JSONObject storedJson = new JSONObject(readJson);
                Log.d("Stored JSON", "" + storedJson);
                JSONObject idJson = storedJson.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONObject single = idJson.getJSONObject(runeId[0]);

                try {
                    name = single.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return name;
        }
    }
```

My logcat:

```
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:223)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData.getRuneInfo(GetStaticData.java:36)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesActivity.java:150)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesActivity.java:46)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 19:00:30.237      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:165)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:156)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-29 19:00:30.241      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:223)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData.getRuneInfo(GetStaticData.java:36)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesActivity.java:150)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesActivity.java:46)
04-29 19:00:30.245      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:165)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:156)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-29 19:00:30.249      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-29 19:00:30.253      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 19:00:30.253      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:223)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData.getRuneInfo(GetStaticData.java:36)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesActivity.java:150)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesActivity.java:46)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 19:00:30.257      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:165)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:156)
04-29 19:00:30.261      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-29 19:00:30.265      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-29 19:00:30.265      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-29 19:00:30.265      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-29 19:00:30.265      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-29 19:00:30.265      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-29 19:00:30.265      890-890/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-29 19:00:34.009      995-995/edu.appdesign.leaguestats I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 995 SIG: 9
```

GetStaticData.java:165:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("runesInfo.json");
```

GetStaticData:

```
public class GetStaticData {

    private static String api_key = "d96236d2-6ee3-4cfd-afa7-f41bdbc11128";
    public static String region = MainActivity.region.toLowerCase();

    public String getRuneInfo(String runeId) {
        String name = null;
        try {
            name = new GetRunes()
                    .execute(runeId)
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name;
    }

    public String getChampionName(String champId) {
        String name = null;
        try {
            name = new GetChampionName()
                    .execute(champId)
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name;
    }

    public static Summary getSummary(String summId) throws JSONException {
        Summary summary = new Summary();
        try {
            summary = new GetSummary()
                    .execute(summId)
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return summary;
    }

    public static class GetChampionName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        public static String champName;

        protected String doInBackground(String[] champId) {
            String url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/champion/" + champId[0] + "?api_key=" + api_key;
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            Log.i("JSON", "" + jsonObject);
            try {
                champName = jsonObject.getString("key");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return champName;
        }
    }

    public static class GetSummary extends AsyncTask<String, String, Summary> {

        protected Summary doInBackground(String[] summId) {
            String url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + MainActivity.region.toLowerCase() + "/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/" + summId[0] + "/summary?season=SEASON4&api_key=" + api_key;
            Log.i("Summary URL", url);
            String url2 = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + MainActivity.region.toLowerCase() + "/v2.3/league/by-summoner/" + summId[0] + "/entry?api_key=" + api_key;
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArrayParser jsonArrayParser = new JSONArrayParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonArrayParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);
            Summary summary = new Summary();
            Log.i("Stats JSON", "" + jsonObject);
            JSONArray array;
            JSONObject league;
            try {
                array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("playerStatSummaries");
                league = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject rankedStats = array.getJSONObject(4);
                JSONObject normalStats = array.getJSONObject(8);
                summary.rWins = rankedStats.getString("wins");
                summary.rLoss = rankedStats.getString("losses");
                summary.nWins = normalStats.getString("wins");
                summary.rTier = league.getString("tier");
                summary.rLeague = league.getString("leagueName");
                summary.rRank = league.getString("rank");
                summary.rLeaguePoints = league.getString("leaguePoints");
                Log.i("Ranked", "" + summary.rWins + " " + summary.rLoss);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return summary;
        }
    }

    public static class Summary {
        public String rWins;
        public String rLoss;
        public String nWins;
        public String rTier;
        public String rLeague;
        public String rRank;
        public String rLeaguePoints;

        public Summary() {
            super();
        }

        public Summary(String rWins, String rLoss, String nWins, String rTier, String rLeague, String rRank, String rLeaguePoints) {
            super();
            this.rWins = rWins;
            this.rLoss = rLoss;
            this.nWins = nWins;
            this.rTier = rTier;
            this.rLeague = rLeague;
            this.rRank = rRank;
            this.rLeaguePoints = rLeaguePoints;
        }
    }

    public class GetRunes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(String[] runeId) {

            String readJson;
            String name = null;

            try {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("runesInfo.json");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

                fis.read(readJson.getBytes());
                JSONObject storedJson = new JSONObject(readJson);
                Log.d("Stored JSON", "" + storedJson);
                JSONObject idJson = storedJson.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONObject single = idJson.getJSONObject(runeId[0]);


                try {
                    name = single.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't slap "extends Activity" on classes that are not instantiated by the system as an Activity, as you only get a valid Context subsequent to actual lifecycle startup of one by the system. Your class has none of the activity lifecycle methods such as onCreate() etc and is clearly not an Activity. You need a valid Activity or Application or Service context from a bonafide subclass of one of those, not a mis-named helper class such as you have attempted to use here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I had only added that on to test something out previously, and to be honest, completely forgot it was there. Without it, all methods work except reading the saved file. I'm still not even sure the file is being saved.

Comment: openFileInput() **should not exist** in a class that does not inherit from Context, and **will not work** in one that extends a subclass of Context but is not initialized by the Android system.  To use that method, you must pass in a valid, system- **initialized** Context, and call it is a method of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `openFileInput` method:

```
public FileInputStream openFileInput(String name)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        return mBase.openFileInput(name);
}
```

`NPE` is thrown, because `mBase` is `null`. What's the type of `mBase`?

```
Context mBase;
```

I believe your `GetStaticData` class is not inherited from any `Context`-based class. If so, you should provide `Context` by yourself at it's constructor:

```
public GetStaticData(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

And later you should call `openFileInput` using this `Context`:

```
mContext.openFileInput(...)
```

Comment: I believe you are right, but I am still confused. I have edited in my full GetStaticData file for you to look at. Maybe you could tell me more.

Comment: Remove "extends Activity" and you will probably get a build error that shows where you try to misuse a then non-existent Context-derived method. Nikis is showing you here how to do it the right way, and pass in a valid Context at runtime.

Comment: @Nate Ok, you have class inherited from `Activity`, but you are not using it for UI-related things, it's a wrong design. If you need `Context` for some operations, you can just provide it at the constructor, there is no need to extend `Context`-based classes. It's context is not initialized yet, when you call `getRuneInfo`, that's the reason.